# Docker Nginx Django [emerg] host not found in upstream /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf

Tags: django, docker, nginx, rhel, podman

I'm new to web applications landscape and just trying to deploy a basic Django application with Gunicorn, Nginx and podman (version 4.4.1) on Red Hat Linux Enterprise 8.7.
Dockerfile for Nginx is the official image from Docker Hub v 1.25.1.

**There's no docker-compose/podman-compose available on the server.**

I'm starting the build by creating a dedicated network:

`podman network create testapp-net`

The next component is Django application:

`podman build -t testapp-django -f src/testapp-django/compose/django/Dockerfile .`

Dockerfile for the app is based on Ubuntu base image and I'm exposing port 8000:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04
...
RUN addgroup --system django \
    && adduser --system --ingroup django django
...
WORKDIR /app
...
RUN chmod +x /app
...
EXPOSE 8000
...
COPY src/testapp-django/compose/django/entrypoint /entrypoint
RUN sed -i -e 's/^M$//' /entrypoint
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint
RUN chown django /entrypoint

COPY src/testapp-django/compose/django/start /start
RUN sed -i -e 's/^M$//' /start
RUN chmod +x /start
RUN chown django /start

RUN chown -R django:django /app

USER django

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint"]
```

/entrypoint:

```
set -o errexit
set -o pipefail
set -o nounset

exec "$@"
```

/start:

```
set -o errexit
set -o pipefail
set -o nounset

python3 /app/manage.py migrate
gunicorn testapp.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --chdir=/app
```

Starting the Django app is successful:

`podman run -d -p 8010:8000 --name testapp-django --env-file src/testapp-django/.env --network testapp-net testapp-django /start`

Response:

```
[2023-07-07 10:23:41 +0000] [24] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2023-07-07 10:23:41 +0000] [24] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (24)
[2023-07-07 10:23:41 +0000] [24] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2023-07-07 10:23:41 +0000] [26] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 26
```

In the next step I want to start Nginx.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:1.25.1

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY src/testapp-django/compose/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

My nginx.conf file:

```
upstream testapp-django {
    server testapp-django:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://testapp-django;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        client_max_body_size 20M;
    }
}
```

`podman build -t testapp-nginx -f src/testapp-django/compose/nginx/Dockerfile .`

When I run the container though:

`podman run  -p 1337:80 --name testapp-nginx --network testapp-net testapp-nginx`

I'm getting the following response:

```
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf is not a file or does not exist
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Sourcing /docker-entrypoint.d/15-local-resolvers.envsh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
2023/07/07 14:48:34 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "testapp-django:8000" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf:2
nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "testapp-django:8000" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf:2
```

I was looking for solution in similar posts on SO, but without any success.

Inspect on app container, I see the following for the network:

```
  "NetworkSettings": {
       "EndpointID": "",
       "Gateway": "",
       "IPAddress": "",
       "IPPrefixLen": 0,
       "IPv6Gateway": "",
       "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
       "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
       "MacAddress": "",
       "Bridge": "",
       "SandboxID": "",
       "HairpinMode": false,
       "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
       "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
       "Ports": {
            "8000/tcp": [
                 {
                      "HostIp": "",
                      "HostPort": "8000"
                 }
            ]
       },
       "SandboxKey": "/run/user/1632100669/netns/netns-10b5a628-1e92-a4ac-1800-2957e0edaf1c",
       "Networks": {
            "testapp-net": {
                 "EndpointID": "",
                 "Gateway": "10.89.1.1",
                 "IPAddress": "10.89.1.17",
                 "IPPrefixLen": 24,
                 "IPv6Gateway": "",
                 "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                 "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                 "MacAddress": "16:cb:3d:2a:d1:43",
                 "NetworkID": "testapp-net",
                 "DriverOpts": null,
                 "IPAMConfig": null,
                 "Links": null,
                 "Aliases": [
                      "2a14008a1c9d"
                 ]
            }
       }
  }
```

The same on nginx container:

```
"NetworkSettings": {
   "EndpointID": "",
   "Gateway": "",
   "IPAddress": "",
   "IPPrefixLen": 0,
   "IPv6Gateway": "",
   "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
   "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
   "MacAddress": "",
   "Bridge": "",
   "SandboxID": "",
   "HairpinMode": false,
   "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
   "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
   "Ports": {
        "80/tcp": [
             {
                  "HostIp": "",
                  "HostPort": "1337"
             }
        ]
   },
   "SandboxKey": "",
   "Networks": {
        "testapp-net": {
             "EndpointID": "",
             "Gateway": "",
             "IPAddress": "",
             "IPPrefixLen": 0,
             "IPv6Gateway": "",
             "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
             "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
             "MacAddress": "",
             "NetworkID": "testapp-net",
             "DriverOpts": null,
             "IPAMConfig": null,
             "Links": null,
             "Aliases": [
                  "a4a11b846dbc"
             ]
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as a test, can you try to give your upstream an other name?

I mean just editing your `nginx.conf`, so that your docker container and the upstream have different identifiers:

```
upstream testapp-django-upstream {
    server testapp-django:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://testapp-django-upstream;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        client_max_body_size 20M;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean renaming the running container and changing nginx configuration to use the new name? This does not help.

Comment: I added the details above, what I mean :)

Comment: Tried changing the upstream name only, but with the same outcome.

Comment: Can you try not to expose the port of the django container to the host, instead just expose the port inside the attached networks? `podman run -d -p 8010:8000 --name testapp-django --env-file src/testapp-django/.env --network testapp-net testapp-django /start` to `podman run -d --expose 8000 --name testapp-django --env-file src/testapp-django/.env --network testapp-net testapp-django /start`

Comment: Tried that too. Exposing the django container to the host was obsolete, so I removed it and only exposed 8000 as a command in Dockerfile. This still does not help with django container being unavailable for nginx. The only solution I found so far is by creating a pod and running containers within a pod: https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/main/troubleshooting.md#23-container-with-exposed-ports-wont-run-in-a-pod

Comment: Only adding the expose to the dockerfile is not sufficient. If you want to expose it to attached networks, you have to add the `--expose 8000` flag. Have you tried that command together with the Dockerfile including the EXPOSE 8000 line?
Another debug idea would be to install ping inside the container, and execute `ping testapp-django` inside the container with `podman exec testapp-nginx ping testapp-django` to have a look if the name can be resolved to the ip of the container interface.

Comment: If your found solution is sufficient please let me know, so I stop suggesting :D

Comment: The problem is not solved. Having both containers in a pod removed the upstream error, but I think not for a good reason, as only the default landing page of nginx is available and Django app is not served. I'm checking further. Thank you for the suggestions so far.

Comment: You can maybe try to add the docker resolver to the `server` scope inside your `nginx.conf` with the following line: `resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30m;`

Answer (score 0):

Managed to make it work by creating a pod first:

```
podman pod create --name testapp [OTHER OPTIONS]
```

Then all containers are created with
`--pod testapp`
option:

```
podman container create --pod testapp --name testapp-django [OTHER OPTIONS]
```

This way Nginx sees the Django app.

I faced other issues afterwards that had to do with permissions when running in rootless mode, but managed to solve these issues following this post:
https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/container-permission-denied-errors